# GPUImage questions

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, ios7, gpuimage

I'm new to GPUImage framework. I have a question,

Project with GPUImage won't compile with 64bit simulator unless I change project settings to include 64bit architechture (arm64). Is there any disadvantages of keeping this setting on all the time? (If I'm only targeting for iOS 7).

And I don't have an actual 64bit device to test so , I'm wondering if I use default settings which doesn't include arm64 support, will project compile and run on an iPhone 5S? or Should I enable arm64 if I'm planning to run this on 64bit devices. Or is this 64bit setting option, just only related to simulator?

Answer (score 0):

to find out will it run on arm64, you can choose simulation mode to 64.
[image]

Comment: it doesnt run on 64bit simulator when arm64 is not added. It work fine on simulator when arm64 architecture is added. So I asked whether it run on an actual 64bit device without adding that architecture. Because other apps work on 64bit devices without adding arm64 flag.